# How do I center align iframe with a max-width greater than 100% in order to crop some of the iframe width?

Tags: css, iframe, html5-canvas, width, crop

I am using an iframe to display a canvas runtime with the dimensions of 1920x1080.

I want to be able to keep the iframe horizontally centered with a maximum width of 170% so that up to 35% of the iframe can be cropped on either size but the height will always fill 100% of the frame except for when doing so will cause the horizontal width to exceed 170%.

This is my current style code for the iframe. It actually works perfectly except the iframe is always fixed to the left edge of the browser frame so when I shrink the browser horizontally it will crop up to 70% of the frame on the right side only rather than equally on either size.

```
.frame {
  display: flex;
  width:  1920px;
  max-width: 170%;
  height: 100%; 
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none;  
}
```

EDIT: This is how my style is now set up after @Dan's helpful response (added overflow hidden to remove scroll bars)

```
body {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;  
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.frame {

    padding: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    width: 1920px;
    max-width: 170%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  
}
```

See my reply below for the small issue I'm still having.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working with the following setup. The `body` is now `display: flex` and the `iframe` is `position: absolute;`

These two working together gave the desired effect. Let me know how it works out.

```html
<body>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 1920px;
            max-width: 170%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. My outcome seems to be slightly different from yours, and it's almost perfect with just a small exception.

If the browser width is < 1080 then the frame is cropped as expected with 35% of the frame being cropped on either side and the bottom edge of the frame filling with white space to prevent the frame from going above 170% width. This is the desired effect.

Once the browser width reaches 1080+, the right side of the frame will begin to expand at roughly 3x the rate of the left, so the iframe is no longer centered.

Comment: After expanding the browser window by about 200px the left side will expand at the same rate as the right, but it will still be off because of that initial 200px difference.